# Wikipedia api error for images when page is loaded locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia-api

I created a simple web form that pulls a wikipedia article and renders it on the page: https://fiddle.jshell.net/isachenx/b223kth6/

Everything is fine in the fiddle, but when used locally, I get errors when the ajax request tries to get the thumbnail images from the wikipedia page.

The error in the console reads:

> GET file://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Paleis_op_de_dam.JPG/129px-Paleis_op_de_dam.JPG net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

How can I get the request to get the images correctly? Change file:// to https:// ? How?

I don't need the images, but I'd like the console to stop throwing me errors...

Comment: when you run locally, you need run it on a local webserver, not using the file:// protocol. You can easily install IIS (for Windows) or Apache (for Windows, Linux or Mac).

Comment: The fiddle link is broken.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, running it with Apache worked....